# Kids Lunch box - suggestion for fruit smoothie packaging

Tags: fruit, presentation, children, smoothie

Could you suggest how to package a home made fruit smoothie to make it appealing to young children. The kids seem to love [fruit tubes by innocent](http://www.innocentdrinks.co.uk/things_we_make/fruit-tubes/) in their lunch boxes as they are colourful, easy to open and drink from.

How could I pack a home made smoothie to make it equally attractive?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a plastic syringe (without the needle obviously), which can usually be found at cake stores and such.

Where I come from there's a chocolate shop that sells plastic syringes filled with chocolate for kids.

On the other hand, the extended plunger may take up too much room. In that case, maybe a test-tube sort of thing with a plastic top to seal it. I've seen them around, but wouldn't know where to find them.

Comment: interesting, I did not see them in shops around here really (Ireland) but I will keep it in mind

Comment: We have a ton of these large plastic syringes lying around for when our animals get sick and need to have oral medication, so if you can't find what you need in a food store, try a medical supply or vet supply.  You can fill them and cover with foil or plastic wrap and a rubber band and pack the plunger with it separately.  They're really convenient for topping cakes and cookies with, for example as Carmi alluded to, chocolate (picture the lines across girl scout caramel delites).  http://warneronline.com/img_lg/640157_DN-Series_gr.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are [places that sell long, narrow plastic bags](http://www.uline.com/cls_01/Bags-Poly-Plastic?pricode=we402&gclid=CIPUxd_n-6YCFcNM4AodLBhLHA).

I don't know what thickness of bag wall you'd need so there wasn't liklihood of premature rupture in transport, though.  There might be other places where you could get lots of less than 1000, so you're not stuck with them if they don't work.

Comment: are those ok to be used with the foodstuffs?

Comment: @kristof : from the page for 1, 2, and 3 mil clear [Industrial Poly Bags](http://www.uline.com/Grp_3/Poly-Bags-Flat-Open) : Meets FDA and USDA specifications for food contact.  The language on the thicker ones and reclosable bags are a little weaker, eg "All virgin polyethylene film meets FDA and USDA requirements." and "Meets FDA and USDA specifications.", but they all claim to be from the same materials, using slightly different wording (virgin polyethylene film) (note, [a 'mil' is 1/1000th of an inch](http://www.5starwriting.com/ThicknThinofPlasticBags.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

How about a thermos beverage bottle?  If you pre-chill the interior, it should keep the smoothie pretty cold.  Pack a straw along with it, and you're good to go.

Comment: This is certainly the easiest way to do it, but I think the OP wanted to pack it in a way that appealed to the kids fancy. I think Carmi is closer to the right answer.

Comment: @yossarian yes, you are right I am looking for something that the kids would find fancy, they seem to like it simply in the glass at home but the lunch box is another story

Comment: I actually would not mind using a bottle, not necessary isolated as it does not need to be kept too cold. But the bottle would really need to be a tiny one, and ideally colourful as well

Answer (score 0):

We've had great success with those 'Sports' water bottles for kids - hard plastic with a spout on top that is pushed down to seal. Kids seem to love them because they're like the 'Fruit Shoot' bottles that are very popular here in Britain.

But they're pretty big as they're for water - I'd probably vomit if I drank that much fruit smoothie - so not great for really little ones.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something homemade kids like thing from home and are unlikely to eat school lunches because they aren't used to it I suggest maybe a strawberry and banana fruit smoothie

Comment: The question was how to package it. The OP is already making homemade fruit smoothies.

Answer (score -3):

[These](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple) work fine, packaging is edible too

Comment: Interesting.  If only it was easier to hollow out, like a pumpkin.

Comment: Doh!  It's a fruit filled container!  Getting slow in my old age.

Comment: Clever, but really not an answer to the question (unless you'd care to explain how an apple qualifies as a smoothie).

Comment: [In the context of a child lunch box] You take a bite and chew, instant smoothie, works fine, no plastic thingies required :-) Guess how you blend flavours...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothie

Comment: I like it:), it would really be ideal to give all fresh fruits, and I do include them, the idea of the fancy packaged fruit and yoghurt is to make it work as a treat.